# Potion effects in certain radius?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I’m currently making a minecraft server for my friends and I to play on, I’m currently having difficultlies with potion effects. I need to effect all players in a 10 block radius. Not all on the game but only the ones in that radius.
I thought it was:

`/effect @a[r=10] mining_fatiue 2 255`

Comment: Hmm, at a first glance that actually looks right, so I'm not sure what's going on. This command is running for all players @a not just within the radius? Let me double check the selector syntax, but this is strange...

Comment: Aha, I think I found it. Are you in Minecraft version 1.13?

Comment: The user has indicated in my now deleted irrelevant answer that the target version is 1.7.10

Answer (score 3):

you spelt mining_fatigue like mining_fatiue

Answer (score 0):

this is kinda ez question as you can use same command that we mostly use in the portals wich is 
/tp @p[r=3] and that will tp all the players withen 3 blocks of the commandblock so you cn basicily make it effect instead of tp and it will look like

/effect @p[r=15] minecraft:{any effect you want without the prakets}

Ex "/effect @p[r=15] minecraft:speed 3 60"
that command will give all players withen 15 blocks away from te commandblock the effect speed level 3

and untill they leave the area the countdown from 60 will start so they will get the command allways as long as the player is inside the area then when he left it the countdown will start wich is the effect time

"note" set the commandblock to repeating so it willl be giving all the players withen the range the speed effect for 60sec and those 60sec will be regenerating

if you want it to make them lose the effect directly when they leave this area just set the time for 1